# What is a staff restaurant?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "a staff restaurant" mean? I found it in the Oxford Dictionary [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/staff_1?q=staff).

> staff
>
> 1. [countable, usually singular, uncountable] all the workers employed in an organization considered as a group
>
>    - medical staff
>    - (British English) teaching staff
>    - (British English) We have 20 part-time members of staff.
>    - (North American English) staff members
>    - staff development/training
>    - **a staff restaurant**/meeting

Comment: What is difference between 'restaurant staff' and 'a staff restaurant'?

Comment: You should read about [**noun adjuncts**, also called *attributive nouns* or *noun modifiers*](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-when-nouns-act-like-adjectives/2998821.html).  In English, one noun can be used to modify another; the second noun is the "real" noun, and the first one acts like an adjective. So "restaurant staff" is "staff, of the restaurant" and "staff restaurant" is "a restaurant, of the staff".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **staff restaurant** is a restaurant for use by the workers (staff) of a company.

The **restaurant staff** are the workers (staff) of a restaurant.

---

Unfortunatly, as *staff restaurant* is a relatively uncommon term, the best reference for it is from [crossword puzzles](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/staff-restaurant)

> **Canteen**: Staff Restaurant
>   **Cafeteria**: Staff Restaurant